# Cut-off of rank-size distribution in R

Tags: r, distribution

How do you calculate the cut-off of a rank-size distribution, i.e. the x which splits the distribution so that the top x% categories contain 1-x% of observations? For example, if the cut-off is 20%, the top 20% categories contain 80% of the observations.

In the sample below, the categories are `cbsa_code`, frequency is `Freq`, and category rank by frequency is `rank` (some ranks can be equal and decimal because they were calculated with `ties.method = "average"`):

```
structure(list(cbsa_code = c("35620", "41860", "31080", "41940", 
"14460", "47900", "16980", "42660", "33100", "19100", "37980", 
"12420", "12060", "41740", "26420", "38900", "38060", "19740", 
"33460", "29820", "19820", "36740", "45300", "14500", "14860", 
"12580", "17140", "40900", "38300", "41620", "28140", "34980", 
"41180", "20500", "39580", "16740", "17460", "40140", "18140", 
"39340", "41700", "27260", "33340", "26900", "31540", "10580", 
"11460", "32820", "35380", "39300", "35300", "42100", "12540", 
"36420", "40060", "45940", "46140", "25540", "31140", "40380", 
"42200", "46520", "15380", "24340", "35840", "47260", "46060", 
"17820", "49340", "31700", "36540", "37100", "10420", "15980", 
"16700", "19780", "30780", "42220", "10740", "22660", "23540", 
"28940", "39900", "13820", "16580", "16860", "14260", "16940", 
"24860", "29620", "34940", "45780", "16820", "43620", "11700", 
"23420", "25420", "34820", "41500", "12940", "22220", "26620", 
"33860", "41540", "44060", "48900", "11260", "14740", "20100", 
"21660", "27060", "10900", "14580", "15540", "17900", "21340", 
"24660", "29540", "37340", "38860", "44140", "45220", "19380", 
"19660", "26980", "29940", "30460", "36260", "42020", "42340", 
"46340", "11540", "12020", "13380", "17020", "17200", "18700", 
"24580", "24780", "25500", "25900", "26820", "27540", "27940", 
"32780", "34900", "35980", "37860", "42540", "43900", "44300", 
"45060", "46700", "48620", "11100", "12220", "12300", "13460", 
"18180", "19340", "20780", "22140", "27140", "27220", "28420", 
"28700", "28740", "30700", "33260", "33780", "34580", "36860", 
"39460", "41420", "44700", "47380", "48660", "49180", "12700", 
"13100", "13780", "13980", "17660", "18580", "20020", "20260", 
"21140", "21500", "23060", "23860", "24060", "25180", "25200", 
"25860", "26380", "26500", "26740", "27980", "29340", "29460", 
"31060", "36100", "36780", "37460", "38940", "40420", "42140", 
"43780", "44180", "44500", "45860", "46660", "48700", "49620", 
"10780", "11900", "12260", "13220", "13900", "14100", "14540", 
"15940", "16180", "16300", "17340", "17780", "17860", "17980", 
"18660", "20140", "20220", "20420", "20700", "21260", "22020", 
"22500", "22520", "22900", "23180", "23580", "23820", "24300", 
"24420", "24540", "24900", "24940", "25060", "25940", "28020", 
"28060", "28580", "29300", "29660", "30020", "30140", "30420", 
"30860", "30980", "31180", "31340", "31900", "32140", "32580", 
"33140", "33220", "33540", "36140", "36500", "36700", "36980", 
"37900", "38540", "39140", "39420", "39540", "39660", "39740", 
"40660", "41140", "42700", "43060", "43100", "43380", "43580", 
"44100", "44260", "44920", "45460", "45900", "46020", "46540", 
"47460", "49300", "49420", "10100", "10140", "10460", "10620", 
"10700", "11500", "11740", "11820", "12620", "12740", "12900", 
"12980", "13140", "13180", "13740", "14010", "14140", "14380", 
"14700", "15220", "15260", "15500", "15620", "15740", "16100", 
"16220", "16540", "17220", "17300", "17580", "17740", "18020", 
"18220", "18260", "19060", "19140", "19180", "19300", "19580", 
"20380", "20660", "20740", "20820", "21220", "21540", "21580", 
"21700", "21780", "21840", "21900", "22180", "22420", "23300", 
"23460", "23660", "23900", "24020", "24220", "24260", "24620", 
"24640", "25620", "26780", "26860", "27420", "27460", "27900", 
"28100", "28380", "28660", "28780", "29060", "29100", "29200", 
"29380", "29700", "29980", "30300", "30340", "31020", "31300", 
"31380", "31940", "32220", "32260", "32380", "33700", "33740", 
"34100", "34340", "34460", "34620", "34700", "34780", "34860", 
"35460", "35740", "36460", "36940", "37120", "38240", "38380", 
"38820", "39020", "39060", "39820", "39940", "39980", "40220", 
"40260", "40340", "40860", "40980", "41060", "41820", "42820", 
"42860", "42940", "43140", "43260", "43340", "43420", "43740", 
"44220", "44420", "44460", "44660", "45180", "45340", "45380", 
"45620", "45820", "46220", "46300", "46740", "46980", "47180", 
"47220", "47240", "47300", "47620", "47700", "47940", "48020", 
"48060", "48140", "48260", "48580", "48780", "49080", "49220", 
"49660", "10180", "10220", "10300", "10500", "10540", "10660", 
"10820", "10860", "10940", "10980", "11020", "11060", "11140", 
"11180", "11220", "11380", "11420", "11580", "11620", "11660", 
"11680", "11780", "11860", "11940", "11980", "12100", "12140", 
"12180", "12380", "12460", "12660", "12680", "12780", "12820", 
"12860", "13020", "13060", "13260", "13300", "13340", "13420", 
"13500", "13540", "13620", "13660", "13700", "13720", "13940", 
"14020", "14180", "14220", "14340", "14420", "14620", "14660", 
"14720", "14780", "14820", "15020", "15060", "15100", "15180", 
"15340", "15420", "15460", "15580", "15660", "15680", "15700", 
"15780", "15820", "15860", "15900", "16020", "16060", "16260", 
"16340", "16380", "16460", "16500", "16620", "16660", "17060", 
"17260", "17380", "17420", "17500", "17540", "17700", "18060", 
"18100", "18300", "18380", "18420", "18460", "18500", "18620", 
"18740", "18780", "18820", "18860", "18880", "18900", "18980", 
"19000", "19220", "19260", "19420", "19460", "19500", "19540", 
"19620", "19700", "19760", "19860", "19940", "19980", "20060", 
"20180", "20300", "20340", "20460", "20540", "20580", "20900", 
"20940", "20980", "21020", "21060", "21120", "21180", "21300", 
"21380", "21420", "21460", "21740", "21820", "21980", "22060", 
"22100", "22260", "22280", "22300", "22340", "22380", "22540", 
"22580", "22620", "22700", "22780", "22800", "22820", "22860", 
"23140", "23240", "23340", "23380", "23500", "23620", "23700", 
"23780", "23940", "23980", "24100", "24140", "24380", "24460", 
"24500", "24700", "24740", "24820", "24980", "25100", "25220", 
"25260", "25300", "25460", "25580", "25700", "25720", "25740", 
"25760", "25780", "25820", "25840", "25880", "25980", "26020", 
"26090", "26140", "26220", "26300", "26340", "26460", "26540", 
"26580", "26660", "26700", "26940", "26960", "27020", "27100", 
"27160", "27180", "27300", "27340", "27380", "27500", "27600", 
"27620", "27700", "27740", "27780", "27860", "27920", "28180", 
"28260", "28300", "28340", "28500", "28540", "28620", "28820", 
"28860", "28900", "29020", "29180", "29260", "29420", "29500", 
"29740", "29780", "29860", "29900", "30060", "30220", "30260", 
"30280", "30380", "30580", "30620", "30660", "30820", "30880", 
"30900", "30940", "31220", "31260", "31420", "31460", "31500", 
"31580", "31620", "31660", "31680", "31740", "31820", "31860", 
"31930", "31980", "32000", "32020", "32100", "32180", "32280", 
"32300", "32340", "32460", "32500", "32540", "32620", "32660", 
"32700", "32740", "32860", "32900", "32940", "32980", "33020", 
"33060", "33180", "33300", "33420", "33500", "33580", "33620", 
"33660", "33940", "33980", "34020", "34060", "34140", "34180", 
"34220", "34260", "34300", "34380", "34420", "34500", "34540", 
"34660", "34740", "35020", "35060", "35100", "35140", "35220", 
"35260", "35420", "35440", "35500", "35580", "35660", "35700", 
"35820", "35860", "35900", "35940", "36020", "36220", "36300", 
"36340", "36380", "36580", "36620", "36660", "36820", "36830", 
"36840", "36900", "37020", "37060", "37080", "37140", "37220", 
"37260", "37300", "37420", "37500", "37540", "37580", "37620", 
"37660", "37740", "37780", "37940", "38100", "38180", "38220", 
"38260", "38340", "38420", "38460", "38500", "38580", "38620", 
"38700", "38740", "38780", "38840", "38920", "39220", "39260", 
"39380", "39500", "39700", "39780", "39860", "40080", "40100", 
"40180", "40300", "40460", "40540", "40580", "40620", "40700", 
"40740", "40780", "40820", "40940", "41100", "41220", "41400", 
"41460", "41660", "41760", "41780", "42300", "42380", "42420", 
"42460", "42620", "42680", "42740", "42780", "42900", "42980", 
"43020", "43180", "43220", "43300", "43320", "43460", "43500", 
"43660", "43700", "43760", "43940", "43980", "44020", "44340", 
"44540", "44580", "44620", "44740", "44780", "44860", "44900", 
"44940", "44980", "45000", "45020", "45140", "45500", "45520", 
"45540", "45580", "45660", "45700", "45740", "45980", "46100", 
"46180", "46380", "46460", "46500", "46620", "46780", "46820", 
"46860", "46900", "47020", "47080", "47340", "47420", "47540", 
"47580", "47660", "47780", "47820", "47920", "47980", "48100", 
"48180", "48220", "48300", "48460", "48540", "48820", "48940", 
"48980", "49020", "49100", "49260", "49380", "49460", "49700", 
"49740", "49780", "49820"), Freq = c(1812L, 1558L, 1052L, 622L, 
514L, 455L, 395L, 393L, 311L, 266L, 261L, 259L, 249L, 213L, 204L, 
156L, 151L, 141L, 95L, 92L, 91L, 91L, 84L, 76L, 71L, 70L, 68L, 
66L, 64L, 64L, 61L, 59L, 52L, 50L, 46L, 45L, 44L, 44L, 40L, 38L, 
38L, 36L, 35L, 34L, 32L, 31L, 30L, 30L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 24L, 23L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
19L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), rank = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
21.5, 21.5, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29.5, 29.5, 31, 32, 33, 34, 
35, 36, 37.5, 37.5, 39, 40.5, 40.5, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47.5, 
47.5, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 54, 54, 56, 57, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 
64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 64.5, 67, 68.5, 68.5, 71, 71, 71, 75.5, 75.5, 
75.5, 75.5, 75.5, 75.5, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81, 85, 85, 85, 89.5, 
89.5, 89.5, 89.5, 89.5, 89.5, 93.5, 93.5, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 
103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 117, 
117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 117, 127, 127, 127, 
127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 127, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 
143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 143, 
143, 143, 143, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 
166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 
166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 166.5, 196.5, 
196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 
196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 
196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 
196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 254.5, 
254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 
254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 
254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 
254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 
254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 
254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 
254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 
254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 
254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 254.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 
370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 370.5, 447, 448, 449, 450, 
451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 
464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 
477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 
490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 
503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 
516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 
529, 530, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539, 540, 541, 
542, 543, 544, 545, 546, 547, 548, 549, 550, 551, 552, 553, 554, 
555, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566, 567, 
568, 569, 570, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 
581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 
594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 
607, 608, 609, 610, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 
620, 621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 628, 629, 630, 631, 632, 
633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 638, 639, 640, 641, 642, 643, 644, 645, 
646, 647, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652, 653, 654, 655, 656, 657, 658, 
659, 660, 661, 662, 663, 664, 665, 666, 667, 668, 669, 670, 671, 
672, 673, 674, 675, 676, 677, 678, 679, 680, 681, 682, 683, 684, 
685, 686, 687, 688, 689, 690, 691, 692, 693, 694, 695, 696, 697, 
698, 699, 700, 701, 702, 703, 704, 705, 706, 707, 708, 709, 710, 
711, 712, 713, 714, 715, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 721, 722, 723, 
724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 730, 731, 732, 733, 734, 735, 736, 
737, 738, 739, 740, 741, 742, 743, 744, 745, 746, 747, 748, 749, 
750, 751, 752, 753, 754, 755, 756, 757, 758, 759, 760, 761, 762, 
763, 764, 765, 766, 767, 768, 769, 770, 771, 772, 773, 774, 775, 
776, 777, 778, 779, 780, 781, 782, 783, 784, 785, 786, 787, 788, 
789, 790, 791, 792, 793, 794, 795, 796, 797, 798, 799, 800, 801, 
802, 803, 804, 805, 806, 807, 808, 809, 810, 811, 812, 813, 814, 
815, 816, 817, 818, 819, 820, 821, 822, 823, 824, 825, 826, 827, 
828, 829, 830, 831, 832, 833, 834, 835, 836, 837, 838, 839, 840, 
841, 842, 843, 844, 845, 846, 847, 848, 849, 850, 851, 852, 853, 
854, 855, 856, 857, 858, 859, 860, 861, 862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 
867, 868, 869, 870, 871, 872, 873, 874, 875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 
880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887, 888, 889, 890, 891, 892, 
893, 894, 895, 896, 897, 898, 899, 900, 901, 902, 903, 904, 905, 
906, 907, 908, 909, 910, 911, 912, 913, 914, 915, 916, 917)), .Names = c("cbsa_code", 
"Freq", "rank"), row.names = c(597L, 742L, 488L, 743L, 103L, 
878L, 159L, 756L, 539L, 207L, 654L, 54L, 46L, 738L, 378L, 676L, 
655L, 223L, 547L, 459L, 226L, 623L, 820L, 104L, 114L, 57L, 162L, 
722L, 661L, 735L, 422L, 583L, 728L, 242L, 691L, 155L, 170L, 704L, 
185L, 685L, 737L, 401L, 545L, 390L, 499L, 10L, 30L, 532L, 591L, 
684L, 590L, 745L, 56L, 615L, 701L, 836L, 841L, 356L, 489L, 710L, 
747L, 849L, 122L, 328L, 602L, 865L, 839L, 178L, 908L, 504L, 618L, 
635L, 6L, 138L, 154L, 225L, 479L, 748L, 14L, 293L, 310L, 440L, 
698L, 89L, 151L, 157L, 99L, 158L, 342L, 454L, 582L, 832L, 156L, 
781L, 37L, 307L, 353L, 579L, 733L, 67L, 281L, 383L, 556L, 734L, 
791L, 898L, 27L, 111L, 232L, 268L, 395L, 18L, 106L, 126L, 180L, 
261L, 337L, 453L, 641L, 675L, 793L, 819L, 214L, 221L, 393L, 462L, 
474L, 611L, 744L, 750L, 845L, 32L, 45L, 78L, 160L, 163L, 197L, 
334L, 340L, 355L, 368L, 388L, 408L, 417L, 531L, 581L, 606L, 651L, 
754L, 787L, 797L, 816L, 853L, 893L, 23L, 50L, 52L, 80L, 186L, 
213L, 248L, 279L, 397L, 400L, 428L, 434L, 435L, 478L, 543L, 555L, 
573L, 628L, 688L, 731L, 806L, 868L, 894L, 904L, 61L, 71L, 88L, 
92L, 174L, 194L, 230L, 236L, 256L, 265L, 300L, 317L, 322L, 348L, 
349L, 366L, 377L, 380L, 386L, 418L, 448L, 451L, 487L, 608L, 624L, 
643L, 678L, 711L, 746L, 786L, 794L, 801L, 834L, 852L, 895L, 912L, 
15L, 42L, 51L, 74L, 90L, 95L, 105L, 137L, 142L, 145L, 167L, 177L, 
179L, 181L, 196L, 233L, 235L, 240L, 246L, 259L, 276L, 288L, 289L, 
299L, 302L, 311L, 316L, 327L, 330L, 333L, 343L, 344L, 346L, 369L, 
419L, 420L, 431L, 447L, 455L, 464L, 466L, 473L, 481L, 485L, 490L, 
494L, 508L, 515L, 526L, 540L, 542L, 549L, 609L, 617L, 622L, 631L, 
652L, 667L, 681L, 687L, 690L, 692L, 694L, 716L, 727L, 758L, 767L, 
768L, 776L, 780L, 792L, 796L, 811L, 823L, 835L, 838L, 850L, 870L, 
907L, 910L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 31L, 38L, 40L, 58L, 62L, 66L, 
68L, 72L, 73L, 87L, 93L, 96L, 101L, 109L, 119L, 120L, 125L, 128L, 
132L, 141L, 143L, 150L, 164L, 166L, 173L, 176L, 182L, 187L, 188L, 
206L, 208L, 209L, 212L, 219L, 239L, 245L, 247L, 249L, 258L, 266L, 
267L, 269L, 271L, 273L, 274L, 280L, 287L, 304L, 308L, 313L, 318L, 
321L, 325L, 326L, 335L, 336L, 358L, 387L, 389L, 405L, 406L, 415L, 
421L, 427L, 433L, 436L, 442L, 443L, 445L, 449L, 456L, 463L, 470L, 
471L, 486L, 493L, 495L, 510L, 517L, 518L, 522L, 553L, 554L, 561L, 
567L, 570L, 574L, 576L, 578L, 580L, 594L, 600L, 616L, 630L, 636L, 
659L, 663L, 673L, 679L, 680L, 696L, 699L, 700L, 706L, 707L, 709L, 
721L, 724L, 725L, 741L, 761L, 762L, 764L, 769L, 772L, 775L, 777L, 
784L, 795L, 799L, 800L, 805L, 818L, 821L, 822L, 828L, 833L, 843L, 
844L, 854L, 859L, 862L, 863L, 864L, 866L, 873L, 875L, 880L, 882L, 
883L, 885L, 888L, 892L, 896L, 902L, 905L, 913L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 
9L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 39L, 41L, 43L, 44L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 53L, 55L, 
59L, 60L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 69L, 70L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 79L, 81L, 82L, 
83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 91L, 94L, 97L, 98L, 100L, 102L, 107L, 108L, 
110L, 112L, 113L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 121L, 123L, 124L, 127L, 
129L, 130L, 131L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 139L, 140L, 144L, 146L, 
147L, 148L, 149L, 152L, 153L, 161L, 165L, 168L, 169L, 171L, 172L, 
175L, 183L, 184L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 195L, 198L, 199L, 
200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 210L, 211L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 
218L, 220L, 222L, 224L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 231L, 234L, 237L, 238L, 
241L, 243L, 244L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 257L, 260L, 
262L, 263L, 264L, 270L, 272L, 275L, 277L, 278L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 
285L, 286L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 301L, 
303L, 305L, 306L, 309L, 312L, 314L, 315L, 319L, 320L, 323L, 324L, 
329L, 331L, 332L, 338L, 339L, 341L, 345L, 347L, 350L, 351L, 352L, 
354L, 357L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 367L, 370L, 
371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 376L, 379L, 381L, 382L, 384L, 385L, 
391L, 392L, 394L, 396L, 398L, 399L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 407L, 409L, 
410L, 411L, 412L, 413L, 414L, 416L, 423L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 429L, 
430L, 432L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 441L, 444L, 446L, 450L, 452L, 457L, 
458L, 460L, 461L, 465L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 472L, 475L, 476L, 477L, 
480L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 491L, 492L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 500L, 501L, 
502L, 503L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 509L, 511L, 512L, 513L, 514L, 516L, 
519L, 520L, 521L, 523L, 524L, 525L, 527L, 528L, 529L, 530L, 533L, 
534L, 535L, 536L, 537L, 538L, 541L, 544L, 546L, 548L, 550L, 551L, 
552L, 557L, 558L, 559L, 560L, 562L, 563L, 564L, 565L, 566L, 568L, 
569L, 571L, 572L, 575L, 577L, 584L, 585L, 586L, 587L, 588L, 589L, 
592L, 593L, 595L, 596L, 598L, 599L, 601L, 603L, 604L, 605L, 607L, 
610L, 612L, 613L, 614L, 619L, 620L, 621L, 625L, 626L, 627L, 629L, 
632L, 633L, 634L, 637L, 638L, 639L, 640L, 642L, 644L, 645L, 646L, 
647L, 648L, 649L, 650L, 653L, 656L, 657L, 658L, 660L, 662L, 664L, 
665L, 666L, 668L, 669L, 670L, 671L, 672L, 674L, 677L, 682L, 683L, 
686L, 689L, 693L, 695L, 697L, 702L, 703L, 705L, 708L, 712L, 713L, 
714L, 715L, 717L, 718L, 719L, 720L, 723L, 726L, 729L, 730L, 732L, 
736L, 739L, 740L, 749L, 751L, 752L, 753L, 755L, 757L, 759L, 760L, 
763L, 765L, 766L, 770L, 771L, 773L, 774L, 778L, 779L, 782L, 783L, 
785L, 788L, 789L, 790L, 798L, 802L, 803L, 804L, 807L, 808L, 809L, 
810L, 812L, 813L, 814L, 815L, 817L, 824L, 825L, 826L, 827L, 829L, 
830L, 831L, 837L, 840L, 842L, 846L, 847L, 848L, 851L, 855L, 856L, 
857L, 858L, 860L, 861L, 867L, 869L, 871L, 872L, 874L, 876L, 877L, 
879L, 881L, 884L, 886L, 887L, 889L, 890L, 891L, 897L, 899L, 900L, 
901L, 903L, 906L, 909L, 911L, 914L, 915L, 916L, 917L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT: The provided ranks should be disregarded, as `ties.methods = "average"` is the wrong method to use in this case.

Comment: Are you sure it's possible to have 20% of groups to have 80% of count?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik It depends on the distribution. For power-law distributions, it's not uncommon to have high counts on few groups. If you're asking specifically about 20%, that's just an example. My question is precisely about finding out how much. It could be 51% of count in 49% of groups. I don't have the answer in the case of the sample I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon that the top x% categories are defined by the rank, so that the top x% categories is the categories with a rank lower than `max(rank)*x/100`. Then it's actually quite easy to do.

- You calculate cumulative proportions from the counts and convert the ranks to a percentage of the total categories as well,
- You add these to together and check which one is the closest to 1

In R code this could be done like this :

```
get_cutoff <- function(rank, freq){

  counts <- tapply(freq, rank, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
  ranks <- as.numeric(names(counts))

  pdiff <- cumsum(counts / sum(counts)) +  ranks/max(ranks) - 1
  pos <- which.min(abs(pdiff))
  return(ranks[pos]/max(ranks))
}
```

Storing your structure in a data frame called `mydf` gives the following:

get_cutoff(mydf$rank, mydf$Freq)
[1] 0.08833152

To check for yourself this is correct, you can do:

```
> counts <- with(mydf, tapply(Freq, rank, sum, na.rm = TRUE))
> ranks <- as.numeric(names(counts))
> get_cutoff(mydf$rank, mydf$Freq) * max(ranks)
[1] 81
> which(ranks == 81)
[1] 57
> sum(counts[1:57])/sum(counts)
[1] 0.915586
> sum(counts[1:57])/sum(counts) + 81/max(ranks)
[1] 1.003918
```

Due to the discrete nature of ranks, only in specific cases this will be a 100% perfect solution. The algorithm above finds the fraction tied to the rank that gives you the result closest to the perfect solution.

Comment: Very grateful for this! Just a word of caution. In my sample, NA values should actually be 0s (you may have noticed my sample contains no zero frequencies). This is a result of the previous step of my data processing. Changing NAs to 0s before running get_cutoff has a substantial impact on the cutoff value in this case.

Comment: I found that the function is sensitive to ties.methods and this made me realise the OP is misleading. Given a distribution, the cutoff should not depend on ranking method. Hence, the function should apply solely to distribution and integrate ranking. I've rewritten the function accordingly: `get_cutoff <- function(freq){
  freq <- freq[!is.na(freq)]
  freq <- freq[order(freq, decreasing = T)]

  pdiff <- cumsum(freq/sum(freq)) + seq(1,length(freq))/length(freq) - 1
  pos <- which.min(abs(pdiff))
  return(pos/length(freq))
  }`

Comment: Since, as you rightly pointed out, the solution is not a perfect split because ranks are discrete, I would have the function additionally return the matching cumulative frequency: `return(c(pos/length(freq), sum(freq[1:pos])/sum(freq)))`.

Comment: Would you like to integrate my comment(s) (at least the second one) into your answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Comment: @syre I don't mind, but remember that your solution is answering a totally different question. You disregard ranks completely, and reorder your data so the one with the lowest frequency is considered to be of rank 1. And I'm pretty confident that's absolutely not what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the very nice solution by @JorysMeys, here is a leaner solution, which only requires the frequency distribution as an input and which returns the matching share of observations in addition to the cutoff (because the sum will seldom be 100%).

```
get_cutoff <- function(freq){
  # remove NA values from distribution (make sure NA doesn't mean zero before running the function)
  freq <- freq[!is.na(freq)]
  # order distribution by decreasing frequency
  freq <- freq[order(-freq)]
  # subtract 100% from cumulative frequency share plus rank share
  pdiff <- cumsum(freq/sum(freq)) + seq(1,length(freq))/length(freq) - 1
  # position (=rank) of smallest absolute difference (generally not 0 since ranks are discrete)
  pos <- which.min(abs(pdiff))
  # return cutoff of rank share and matching cumulative frequency share
  return(c(pos/length(freq), sum(freq[1:pos])/sum(freq)))
}
```

The reason why there is no need to calculate rank beforehand is that the cutoff should not depend on the `ties.method` argument of rank(). If you do calculate rank beforehand and apply the other solution, then you should use `ties.method = "random"`. Other methods will give uninterpretable results. This solution calculates a simple rank with `seq(1,length(freq))`, which is strictly equivalent to `ties.method = "random"`.

Comment: But here you rank the frequencies, not the observations. So you're effectively turning the frequencies into the random distribution of interest, as opposed to the original distribution.

Comment: @JorisMeys My original intention (and, also my original action, unless I made a mistake, e.g. the `ties.method`) was to rank frequencies. That is the meaning of a rank-size distribution. Sorry I wasn't clear.